# Remind the user to add a Winforms/WPF/asp.net tag when c# tag is given

Tags: feature-request, tags

Too often on StackOverflow the first comment to a question tagged with `c#` is

***Are you using Winforms, WPF, or asp.net?!***

Perhaps the system should nudge a user to add one of these tags if the user tags `c#`.
Of course some questions are purely `c#` and are not related to a certain UI system, that's why I'm suggesting a reminder, not a requirement.

Comment: Don't forget Silverlight, WinRT, etc.

Comment: @slugster Yes, those too. Also, I guess it's also partially relevant for other dotnet languages, not just c#.

Comment: While it will be good, there's just no end for this. What you suggest is creating extra layer of "sub tags" for each tag and honestly, I think it's just too complicated to be worth the effort. Not to mention the discomfort it will cause for those asking pure C# questions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I see where you're coming from, though regarding the discomfort to pure c# questions - I think that would only happen in case of a bad implementation of the reminder box.

Comment: I don't think I've every asked a UI question.... so a reminder to add a UI tag would bug the heck out of me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this prompt is warranted, but if it is, it belongs in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), not as an extra UI feature. The [tag wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) is the place for basic advice about the tag, including a description of what the tag means and recommendations for when to use it and what other tags might be relevant in addition to or instead of that tag.

Comment: I agree with you that the tag wiki is probably the correct place, but I strongly suspect most users, especially new ones don't look at it all.